# How to execute overrided method C++

Tags: c++, overriding, abstract-class

i'll try to create a structure for executing an overrided method in derived class.
My base code structure:

**Base.h** EDITED

```
class Base 
{
protected:
    virtual void Initialize() = 0;
    virtual void Update() = 0;
public:
    void Init();
    void Upd();
};
```

**Base.cpp**

```
#include "Base.h"

void Base::Initialize() {}
void Base::Update() {}

void Base::Init() {
    // Some logic

    Initialize();
}

void Base::Upd() {
    // Some logic

    Update();
}
```

The following class is the class to be inherited from N other classes that implement Initialize() and Update() then:

**Behaviour.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Base.h"

class Behaviour : public Base 
{
protected:
    virtual void Initialize();
    virtual void Update();
};
```

**Behaviour.cpp**

```
#include "Behaviour.h"

void Bheaviour::Initialize() {
    std::cout << "Initialize called!" << std::endl;
}

void Bheaviour::Update() {
    std::cout << "Update called!" << std::endl;
}
```

Then I want to execute Behaviour Initialize() and Update() when is executed in the Base class. My main function is:

**Core.cpp** EDITED

```
#include "Behaviour.h"

int main() {
    Base* base = new Behaviour();

    base->Init();
    while(!quit) {
        base->Upd();
    }
}
```

Thank's in advance for any suggestions!

**Thanks for all suggestions, i've solved!**

Comment: You need an object of the appropriate type. Read about virtual functions in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `Base* base = new Base();`

to

```
Base* base = new Bheviour;
```

and polmorphism will take care of everything else.
If you don't want to create an object out of base class better to declare it as an abstract class.

Comment: I would declare Initialize and Update as pure virtual functions (= 0). This will make Base an abstract class and you won't be able to create an instance of Base, only instances of derived classes.